# Ruby irb having compatibility issues in Windows

Tags: ruby, windows, output

The Windows Ruby and irb was giving no output, partial lines of output or complaining about encountering \r in the middle of a line. After some experimentation I figured out what was happening and thought it might help someone else to post and answer even though it was pretty basic.

Comment: Hi David! Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for thinking of contributing some knowledge to the community! I would just try and go more into detail about what the problem was and the steps that didn't work when troubleshooting in the question, then put the way that you got the answer in an answer. Otherwise, your question won't be particularly useful to others. Also, ask the question as though you don't already know the answer. Pretend that you don't know how to fix it in the question, and add how you fixed it in the answer. You should sound like different people in the question and the answer.

Comment: If you fix up the question, you have my +1

Answer (score 0):

Ruby doesn't work well with the Windows end of line character even though you installed the Windows version. You should make the EOL character the *NIX one. If you happen to use Notepad++, just open the file, and choose Edit -> EOL Conversion -> UNIX(LF) and it will fix all the EOL characters and any new EOL characters will be correct. Whichever selection there is grayed out, is the one you already have.